# upload.parseRequest(request) returns empty list in commons.fileUpload

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload, jboss-4.0.x

I am using `org.apache.commons.fileUpload.FileItem` and other related classes for uploading files from local machine to server (Although for the current testing both the machines are same).

I am having `.jsp` file as UI and servlet to handle the upload. Now when the request reaches
statement

```
List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

it returns empty list. I googled this thing at many places. Most of them specifying the symptons that `parserequest()` returns empty. But Could not find out the exact solution to avoid this. At one place I could see that Tomcat may have filters that may have parsed The request and thats why at above call to parseRequest returns empty list. But there is no specification how to avoid this.

Is it because of the web server I am using (which is JBOss) ? or has it anything to do with the java version and commons.jar version conflicts ?

I am using

- jre 1.6
- jboss-4.0.4.CR2
- commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
- Eclipse (To create dynamic web project)

Your help would be very much useful.

Comment: You will find your solution in below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638210/how-do-i-pass-additional-info-with-input-type-file

Answer (score 15):

I encountered this same problem with a similar setup in Tomcat. The solution was as simple as placing a name attribute on my input file element.

Before I had `<input type="file" />` in my HTML form.

Once I added a name tag i.e. `<input type="file" name="aFile" />` my DiskFileUpload object stopped returning an empty list when I called parseRequest(request) from the servlet/JSP.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I was using a GXT component. I added the name to the uploadfileField and it worked as you said. Thanks !

Comment: This does not help in my case, also you forgot to add the `multiple` attribute: `<input type="file" name="aFile" multiple="true" />`, but even with that I get an empty list although I see the files uploaded correctly in Chrome Network inspector. What's the solution to this?

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jboss 5.1 and have no troubles using commons-fileupload libs. 
Make sure you have the right version of jboss 4.0.4 (jre 1.6) as it may only support jre 1.5. You may want to consider upgrading to the next version if 1.6 is a requirement or change your jre to 1.5.

You should post more of you java and JSP code so we can see how you are posting the request. 
Good Luck